# Code to block day in my daterangepicker is ruining my calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Another very basic question I'm sure. I have a Wordpress site that i'm trying to modify the daterangepicker (exclude certain days). I have the script for this but it ruins the data in my date range.

My original script is:

```
var calendar= jQuery("#" + in_date).daterangepicker(
    options,
    function (start, end, label) {
        start_date  = start.format(date_format);
        end_date    = end.format(date_format);

        in_date_front.val(start_date);
        out_date_front.val(end_date);
        who_is=1;
        booking_started=1;
        jQuery('.wpestate_calendar').removeClass('minim_days_reservation')
            .removeClass('wpestate_min_days_required');
        
        var prop_id=jQuery('#listing_edit').val();
        wpestate_setCookie('booking_prop_id_cookie',  prop_id , 1);
        wpestate_setCookie('booking_start_date_cookie',  jQuery('#start_date').val() , 1);
        wpestate_setCookie('booking_end_date_cookie',  jQuery('#end_date').val() , 1);
        
        show_booking_costs();    
    }
);
```

The following code will only allow certain days, but it ruins my start date:

```
isInvalidDate: function(day) {
if (day.day() === 0 || day.day() === 6) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
```

Can someone please tell me the proper way I can add this new code, if I do it currently it ruins my daterangepicker values.

#### Update:

Adding images of datepicker shared in comments:

Working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e6E1.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElR8b.png

Broken: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVcgf.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBoYO.png

Comment: If `day` is a javascript Date object there is no `day()` method and you are probably seeing errors in dev tools console but no errors are mentioned. Creating a runnable demo would help. You should be able to use a CDN version of the plugin and jQuery to create one a a stack snippet by clicking on `<>` in question editor

Comment: `it currently it ruins my daterangepicker values` - what on earth does that mean? Please be specific when describing your problem, explain what you tried, what you see, copy-paste error msgs, etc. Nobody can guess what you mean.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Charlietfl and don't panic.  Thank you for your replies.

I tried to explain my best but English and google translate are often substandard. Let me try again with pictures.

My current daterangepicker acts like this.
https://i.imgur.com/0H9HlWA.png
https://i.imgur.com/irEdU31.png
This is my daterangepicker and it returns the start date and end date into the correct boxes.

Now when I add the code to only allow certain dates it changes my daterange visually, and the start date and end date is all on the same field.
https://i.imgur.com/K16QcK1.png
https://i.imgur.com/MbdSaim.png

Comment: I ran out of comments above, I appreciate your help.  As you can see the second pictures show it has blocked the certain dates but it returns my start-date and end-date into the same field in a long format.

Comment: Your English is fine! :-) But we need descriptions of the problem, eg "Now I get dates in a format I don't want, like '2020-05-10T00:00:00+1".  This is better than screenshots also, bcs text can be indexed, and others can find it.  Anyway, I tried your code - it works fine, but it depends on your `date_format`.  [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/6147ua9n/) (simplified - remove whatever is not part of this problem).

Comment: Thank you Don't Picnic,
That method does not work for me, I have found that it achieves the goal of blocking the days and returning the start date and end date, but it fails to populate the calendar with already booked days, or days marked as reserved. This was fine on a un-molested calendar but I cannot achieve both goals.
Thank you for your time.